# Jasmine spying on method that calls external method (Angular 2)

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, jasmine

In my angular 2 app, How do I test if my external method (dependency) inside my main method is being called accordingly.

For instance,

```js
Class ServiceA
{
  constructor(
    private serviceB : ServiceB
  ){}


  //How do I test this method to make sure it does what it should ?
  mainMethod()
  {
    //External method
    this.serviceB.otherMethod();

    this.sideMethod();
  }

  sideMethod()
  {
    //Do something
  }
}

Class ServiceB
{
  constructor(){}

  otherMethod()
  {
    //Do something
  }
}
```

Here's what I've tried so far

```js
it('On otherMethod returns false, do something', 
  inject([ServiceA, ServiceB], (serviceA: ServiceA, serviceB: ServiceB) => {
    spyOn(serviceB, 'otherMethod').and.returnValue(false);
    spyOn(serviceA, 'sideMethod');
    spyOn(serviceA, 'mainMethod').and.callThrough();


    expect(serviceB.otherMethod()).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(serviceA.sideMethod()).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(serviceA.mainMethod()).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

From above code, I got an error stating

> could not find an object to spy upon for otherMethod()

What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the function reference of your spy `serviceB.otherMethod`. You are currently invoking the spy by calling `serviceB.otherMethod()` which will return the return value of `otherMethod` instead of the spy.

```
it('On otherMethod returns false, do something', 
    inject([ServiceA, ServiceB], (serviceA: ServiceA, serviceB: ServiceB) => {
    spyOn(serviceB, 'otherMethod').and.returnValue(false);
    spyOn(serviceA, 'sideMethod');
    spyOn(serviceA, 'mainMethod').and.callThrough();

    // Notice spy reference here instead of calling it.
    expect(serviceB.otherMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(serviceA.sideMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(serviceA.mainMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

Jasmine documentation: https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies

Comment: I figured it out minutes after I post this question, thanks anyway man!